# gcloud command says `pyenv: python2: command not found` even if python2 is valid in terminal

Tags: macos, python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm using macOS Mojave 10.14.2, and pyenv 1.2.7 .

And these are my configs of pyenv.
python2 seems to work in the terminal.

```
$ pyenv versions
  system
* 2.7.14
  3.6.4

$ pyenv global
2.7.14
3.6.4

$ pyenv local
2.7.14

$ python2
Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 12 2018, 16:35:37)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> (It works!)
```

But when I use `gcloud` command, it fails saying it cannot find python2.

```
$ gcloud config list
pyenv: python2: command not found

The `python2' command exists in these Python versions:
  2.7.14
```

On the other hand, `npm` command, which requires python2 too, works fine.

It get fixed by `pyenv shell` command temporarily, but it is valid only until I close the terminal.
(The solution is referred here: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1159)

```
$ pyenv shell 2.7.14 3.6.4
$ gcloud config list -> Works!
```

How to fix this problem permanently ?

Comment: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#choosing-the-python-version

Comment: I think my setting up is fine.

Answer (score 6):

I was recently encountering this error and found a solution. I am using pyenv with virtual env (pyenv-viritualenv) and I was attempting to run `gcloud` from inside my python 3 virtual environment.

The issue is that when you run `gcloud` from a location within the virtualenv, it only knows of the python versions specified in the `.python-version` file for that directory. You therefore have to specify a python 2 version to run in addition to your python 3 version:

```
pyenv local <virtualenv name> <python 2 version>
```

I did this in addition to doing the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON bit mentioned in answers on other related questions:

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=$(which python2)
```

I added this to my `.bash_profile`

Comment: is there a way to have it ignore python2 altogether? doesnt it support python3 100% now?

Comment: It looks like gcloud is still set to use python2 by default (see https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-macos#before-you-begin). According to their note on that page, you can run `gcloud topic startup` and follow instructions to force the use of python3, though a few components are still not compatible with python3.

Answer (score 0):

if when you type python on the terminal, it shows different python versions. for example you want to point out to 3.9.0 version. you can type `pyenv global 3.9.0`